# Getting total amount of rows with a certain value C# WPF Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I need to check my `tblProjects` table, in the foreign key column "**ClientID**", for a value that matches the **"ClientLoginID"**(primary key) value in my `tblClientLoginDetails` table and I want to display the **total** **amount** of columns that match that value in a label.

Here is coding where I have tried to do so, but it doesn't display any info in my label. I think it might be because of it getting multiple values and not knowing what to do with it.

```
using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    int CurrentClient = CLD.UserID;

    var Count = DC.tblProjects.Where<tblProject>
                  (c => c.ClientID == CurrentClient);
                  lblTotalProjectsAmount.Content = Count;
}
```

Also I am not getting any errors with the code above?

Sorry if the question sounds vague, but I do not know how to ask it in another way. For any advice or answers, I would be very greatfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forget to use the `Count()` at the end of your linq:

```
 using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
 {
    int CurrentClient = CLD.UserID;

    var Count = DC.tblProjects.Where<tblProject>
            (c => c.ClientID == CurrentClient).Count(); //THIS LINE

    lblTotalProjectsAmount.Content = Count;
}
```

Alternatively you may try something like this:

```
 using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
 {
    int CurrentClient = CLD.UserID;

    var Count = DC.tblProjects.Count(c => c.ClientID == CurrentClient); //THIS LINE

    lblTotalProjectsAmount.Content = Count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! This got it fixed :D